# Changing input value text color using javascript

Tags: javascript, onload, propertychanged

I'm newbie in JavaScript and I want to change the input element text Color but nothing happen when I load the page where I made a Mistake ?

```
<head>
<script language="text/javascript">
        function chngcolor()
        {
            var x=document.getElemetById('status')[0].value;
            if(x=='Accept')
            {
                x.style.color = '#00FF00';

            }

        }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="chngcolor();">

<form>
<input type='text' name='status' id='status' value="Accept" >
</form>


</body>
```

Comment: You misspelled & misused `getElementById`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
function chngcolor() {
    var x = document.getElementById('status');
    if (x.value == 'Accept') {
        x.style.color = '#00FF00';
    }
}
```

`getElementById` returns single DOMElement, so you don't need `[0]`. You also misspelled `getElemetById`.

Comment: I have another question how can I do this for a while loop input ? I mean I want every input with this 'id' runs the JS function but how can I do it ? I tried onload="" in input but it didn't work .

Comment: some how like you code this what I want to do :http://jsfiddle.net/anonymox/zmEMU/    obviusly jsfiddle can't run php code but this is what i want to do.

Comment: never mind i did it with this code :  <?php if($row['status']=="Accept"){$color="green";}else if($row['status']=="Reject"){$color="red";}
                   echo"<td align='center'><input  class='styled-input' style=' font-family: Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif; font-size: 12px;  padding: 5px; width: 80px;margin-right:2px;margin-left:2px;color:".$color.";' "?> type='text' name='status' id='status' value= "<?php echo $row['status']; ?>"></td>